# Redock a floating toolbox in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Inkscape 0.92 in Ubuntu 18.04

I have detached a toolbox (the layers toolbox) and made it a free floating window, but then it is impossible to redock it in the right toolbox dock in Inkscape

Comment: Yeah, in the beginning, it also took me many trials until I found the solution (see answer). This is not really intuitive, IMO, and could be improved. The top bar should also allow docking, just like in other programs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't drag with the window bar. Put your mouse on the panel title underneath, and drag from there.

[image]

Also, aim for the top of the right hand panel, or Inkscape may put your toolboxes in two columns.

Comment: An alternative way (in case dragging really isn't working for someone) is to (with Inkscape closed) edit `/Users/username/.config/inkscape/preferences.xml`, search for "layers" to find `id="layers"` and inside that group change `state="1"` to `state="2"`. Save the XML file and re-launch Inkscape. Note that `.config` is a hidden folder, so make sure your OS is set to show hidden files and folders (on recent Macs the shortcut **Cmd Shift .** will toggle this.)